# How does ASP.Net Eval() work?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Can someone please explain how Eval really works in ASP.NET?

I understand that Eval is just an expression for [DataBinder.Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck.aspx) but I want to know what is actually happening behind the scenes.

I read that DataBind happens on the controls PreRender, but that confuses me because I can call the controls .DataBind() function at anytime.

At what point does the Eval statement become actual text?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation with all `overloads` decompiled with ILSpy. This will help you.

```
public static object Eval(object container, string expression)
{
if (expression == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
}
expression = expression.Trim();
if (expression.Length == 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
}
if (container == null)
{
    return null;
}
string[] expressionParts = expression.Split(DataBinder.expressionPartSeparator);
return DataBinder.Eval(container, expressionParts);
}



public static string Eval(object container, string expression, string format)
{
object obj = DataBinder.Eval(container, expression);
if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
{
    return obj.ToString();
}
return string.Format(format, obj);
}


 private static object Eval(object container, string[] expressionParts)
 {
object obj = container;
int num = 0;
while (num < expressionParts.Length && obj != null)
{
    string text = expressionParts[num];
    if (text.IndexOfAny(DataBinder.indexExprStartChars) < 0)
    {
        obj = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(obj, text);
    }
    else
    {
        obj = DataBinder.GetIndexedPropertyValue(obj, text);
    }
    num++;
}
return obj;
}
```